# Java doesn't compile in .bat if the code imports a library

Tags: java, batch-file, import

I am trying to execute my java code using batch file. The problem I encountered is, that **Kalkulacka.java** just doesn't execute and skips to the next line in batch file. If I remove

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

from **Kalkulacka.java** it executes normally (Except of course java errors caused by removing that line).

**kalkulacka.bat**

```
set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin"
javac Kalkulacka.java
pause
```

**Kalkulacka.java**

http://pastebin.com/xjiw6X5N

PS: kalkulacka means calculator

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks so much for help.

Comment: You need to set a classpath; see - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: I do have classpath set.

Comment: Technically you are trying to compile your Java code not execute it.  That code as written in the paste bin compiles without error.  Please edit your question to include the exact error javac is issuing for your code.  I suspect @NickHolt is correct here. That code will not compile if you remove the import statement as you indicate.

Comment: There is no error thrown. It says executing file and then it skips to pause.

Comment: Post file full output of running kalkulacka.bat.  It's hard for people here to answer questions for you when we don't have all the information you have available.  There is no way that code compiles if you remove the import.

Comment: <filedirectory>javac Kalkulacka.java
<filedirectory>pause
Press any key to continue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is compilable language.

`javac Kalkulacka.java` produce `Kalkulacka.class` (and mayby some more `.class` files)

To run it you need to run `java -cp . Kalkulacka`

`-cp .` set your class path to current directory

`Kalkulacka` is full name of your main class (if you have package declaration you need to prepend package to class name)

ps: I suggest you to use some IDE like Eclipse or InteliJ Idea. It will do lot of such things for you

Comment: Thanks so much!
BTW: I use Idea normally but I just wanted to execute it without emulator.